# Why didn't Grace go traveling with the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who movie, why didn’t Grace end up traveling with the Doctor after saving him from the Master?

> **DOCTOR:** *Grace, something you should know*
>   **GRACE:** *Don't tell me.*
>   **DOCTOR:** *Why not?*
>   **GRACE:** *I know who I am, and that's enough.*
>   **DOCTOR:** *I'm glad. Come with me.*
>   **GRACE:** *You come with me.*
>   **DOCTOR:** *Me come with you?*
>   **GRACE:** *Yes.*
>   **DOCTOR:** *Me come with you? It's tempting.*
>   **GRACE:** *I'm going to miss you.*

I’m looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: Are you looking for an in-universe answer or a production answer? Many of the Doctor Who cast changes are at least partially because the contract of the actor/actress didn't got renewed.

Comment: In universe answer

Answer (score 6):

The simplest explanation is that she refused his offer because she was reluctant to find out about the future, either her personal future or the future in general. It's also worth noting that literally *her entire life* has been devoted to becoming a doctor and saving people's lives. Giving that up is too big of a wrench for her.

The scene plays out slightly differently in the novelisation (based on the original script, not the modified screenplay):

> *The Doctor laughed. ‘Well, Grace, now that you mention it, you ought
>   not to –’ ‘Don’t,’ she said firmly. ‘Why not?’* **‘Because I know who I
>   am. That’s enough.’**
>
> ...
>
> *‘I’d better be off, too.’ The Doctor half turned towards the TARDIS.
>   ‘Do you want to come with me?’ Grace pointed back downtown. ‘Do you
>   want to come with me?’ The Doctor glanced at the TARDIS, back towards
>   the city and then at Grace.* **‘I’m tempted...’ Grace nodded. ‘I guess
>   you are. So am I.’** *She reached forward and hugged him. One last time.*

---

Elsewhere in what laughingly passes for the Doctor Who canon, she *did* end up traveling with him in the various comics (The Fallen, The Glorious Dead, The Flood, Hunters of the Burning Stone) and prose novels (Death of the Doctor)